# SQL Transaction with if statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, transactions

I am trying to do my homework and I am not sure how to make this a transaction and get it to work properly.

Question: 
1. Create a transaction to enter a new tournament.

a. Check to see whether tournament that has ID 21 and tourney location ‘TAMUC’ is
inserted into table ‘tournaments’ (1 point).

b. If there is no record, tournament that has ID 21, ‘2016-11-29’ Tourney Date, and
‘TAMUC’ Tourney Location is entered into the table ‘tournament’ (1 point).

c. Accept all changes in the end of the transaction (1 point)

Code:

```
Select TourneyID, TourneyLocation
From Tournaments
Where TourneyID = 21 and TourneyLocation = 'TAMUC';

if null

INSERT INTO TOURNAMENTS
VALUES (21, '2016-11-29', 'TAMUC');

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use (all-at-once):

```
BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO Tournaments(TourneyID, TourneyDate, TourneyLocation)
SELECT 21, '2016-11-29', 'TAMUC'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1
                 From Tournaments
                 Where TourneyID = 21 and TourneyLocation = 'TAMUC');

COMMIT;
```

For one simple `INSERT INTO` there is no need for transaction (it will be implicit transaction).

Comment: But the homework says that it must be a transaction.

Comment: Ahhh the the word begin tran makes it a transaction. Ok. I think I am beginning to understand this now.